# Can we create reports using EXTJS?

Tags: extjs

I want to know if we can create reports using EXTJS.
Thnx a lot

Comment: What exactly do you mean by reports?

Comment: You really need to provide more detail about what you want to achieve (and accept some more answers, 17% is very unimpressive).

Comment: Hello,
sorry for the rates :s I'll mark them today.
well, I generate some content from my databases in my EXTJS forms, but I don't want to re-generate it again in itext or jasperreports, so, I want to use directly the grids to create the reports that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't create reports with EXTJS. There are tools appropriate for reporting. All of them, server side.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can create reports with any programming tool.  Some are more appropriate than others.  Sounds more like you are specifically talking about "generating reporting data"?

Comment: Hello,
thnx for your answers.
@Pablo Santa Cruz : I used JasperReports for generating some data tables. But it's not really nice, like EXTJS grids, charts ... this is why.
@bmoeskau : yes I want generate reporting data.

Answer (score 5):

If you simply mean that you want to format reporting data received from the server into visual charts or graphs (or tabular / grid format) the answer is yes.  Look at the `Ext.chart` package in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.AbstractChart).  Other than that, you'd have to provide some details on what you're trying to do.

**EDIT**: I'm still not 100% clear on what you're asking, but if you already have working grids and you want to display the same data in a different format for reporting, this is certainly possible.  However, you would not use the grid directly, you would use the underlying `Ext.data.Store` and bind it to some other component that can output your report.  The most obvious solution that comes to mind would be using a [View](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.view.View) (previously `DataView`) to bind your existing store to a custom [XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) that would generate your report view.

Comment: Hello, thnx for your answer.
I want to create reports from the charts or grids I created before in EXTJS, so that I can include them in a PDF report. Can you see what I want ???

Comment: im trying to do something similar, i want to use my already created charts (maybe get an image of it) and put it in my report im actually creating with itextsharp..is that possible?if so ,how?ty

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS with "media='print'" like this:

`< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css"  media="print">`

This CSS will be used by the browser only when the user are trying to print the page. Then, you can change the entire style of the page to look like a report.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server side job. Here is what I use for generating tabular reports which are based on Grid data: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Also, you can generate a very nice, fully functional Excel spreadsheet from tabular data: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/lib...ffice.10).aspx